# How can I import a javascript library into a simple .js file?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to use pandas-js to make a dataframe in my javascript file. How do I import pandas-js into it?

I have downloaded the pandas-js zip file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>This is first prog</title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="./series.js" type="module"></script>
<script>
    import {Series} from './series.js';
    const df = new Series([1, 2, 3, 4], {name: 'Dataframe1'});
    document.write(ds_1.toString());
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

It shows errors in import statement.

Comment: You'll need to use `type="module"` if you wan to use `import` syntax

Answer (score 0):

You can use the script `type="module"` like this *(even what @[Bergi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1048572/bergi)  said already)*:

```
...
...
<body>
<script type="module">
    import {Series} from './series.js';
    const df = new Series([1, 2, 3, 4], {name: 'Dataframe1'});
    document.write(ds_1.toString());
</script>
</body>
...
...
```